# jQuery Validation invalidHandler not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin. When the submission is invalid, the `invalidHandler` callback is not getting called.

```
$j('#my_form').validate({
    errorClass: 'fieldError',
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        ...
    },
    messages: {
        ...
    },
    invalidHandler: function () {
        console.log('invalidHandler');
    },
});
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` on the last line. Aren't you getting a syntax error in the Javascript console?

Comment: Sorry, that was a pasting error. Fixed it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reorder the `options` object so that `invalidHandler` is first.

This shouldn't change the behavior because according to the ECMAScript standard, object properties have no order. However most browsers maintain the order of object properties anyway, so the plugin must be using the object in a non-standard way. Solution found [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validation-invalidhandler-not-firing#14737000002406434).

```
$j('#my_form').validate({
    invalidHandler: function () {
        console.log('invalidHandler');
    },
    errorClass: 'fieldError',
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        ...
    },
    messages: {
        ...
    },
});
```

Comment: There's no way this can be the right answer. Object properties don't have any order.

Comment: Exactly @Barmar.  This answer is nonsense and the linked location is not even a URL.  Even if the order mattered, which it doesn't, there is still a JavaScript syntax error that would prevent this from doing anything.

Comment: I fixed the URL, sorry about that. The syntax error in the question was a paste error and is also fixed. Changing the order of the object properties did actually solve the problem for me and for the poster of the linked post. I am aware the object properties have undefined order according to the ECMAScript standard, but most browsers maintain the order anyway. So it must be that the jQuery Validation Plugin uses the object in a non-standard way.

Comment: I have added a bit about the non-standard behavior to my answer.